# Tree elements initialized with references to emplaced deque members results in nullptr for this

Tags: c++, c++17

The [following program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d02e382baf2f26d) attempts to create a tree of nodes consisting of references to `std::deque` elements.

```
#include <deque>

struct Node;
using Pool = std::deque<Node>;

struct Node
{
    Node(int d, Pool& pool)
        : level{d}
        , l{d > 0 ? pool.emplace_back(d - 1, pool) : *this}
        , r{d > 0 ? pool.emplace_back(d - 1, pool) : *this}
    {
    }

    int level;
    const Node& l;
    const Node& r;

    int check() const
    {
        if(!(&l == this))
            return l.check() + 1 + r.check();
        else
            return 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int depth{2};
    Pool pool;
    Node c(depth, pool);
    return c.check()==7 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

It creates the correct number of elements, but not all references are initialized to the emplaced elements and the `level` variable is not set for levels higher than `0`.

Finally, program fails due to `this` being a `nullptr` when the `check()` function is executed.

How can the references be correctly initialized?

Comment: What happens when you call `check()` when `&r == this` but `&l != this`?

Comment: @cdhowie Could that happen? Given that the only constructor applies the same rule to both `&l` and `&r`?

Comment: Hang, not sure actually...

Comment: Could it be that the implementation of `deque` you're using is not Standard-compliant and invalidates references?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Could be, this fails on both MSVC and gcc. I haven't tried clang yet.

Comment: Could be something with the way arguments are forwarded to the constructor. Replacing `emplace_back(d - 1, pool)` with `emplace_back(Node(d - 1, pool))` seems not to crash.

Comment: @AMA that might be undefined behavior as the `Node` is destroyed after the constructor exits.

Comment: @AMA, upon second thought that might actually work if `std::deque` uses the copy constructor. It just happens to still fail for the same reasons as the original program.

Comment: @AMA That is a very interesting idea. It does not suffer from the original problem (see my answer) and no parent ends up referring to a temporary child that was already destructed. The problem is that in the leaf nodes, instead `this` in `l` and `r` they end up with a reference to the destroyed temporary.

Comment: I think the fundamental problem is that `emplace_back` returns `back()`, which will not be the expected element when the constructor of the emplaced element adds another element to the deque.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm It depends on how `std::deque` is implemented on what exactly goes wrong. For example, perhaps it does a placement new on the final element, and ends up doing a placement new in the same place. Or some other weird thing.

Comment: @AMA I actually got your idea to work by just tweaking the copy constructor. I think I have actually finished my answer now :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Summary

The problem is that you're calling `emplace_back` on the `deque` *from* a constructor being called by `emplace_back`. You are not allowed to modify a container while one of its methods is already in progress. This is prohibited by [section [reentrancy] of the C++ standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/reentrancy) (thanks to @T.C.).

> Except where explicitly specified in this International Standard, it is implementation-defined which functions in the C++ standard library may be recursively reentered.

To see why this sort of thing isn't allowed, here is a more obvious example. Imagine calling `std::vector::push_back()` from a copy constructor which is being invoked by `std::vector` during reallocation for another `push_back()` in progress. Reallocation works by allocating the new chunk of memory before freeing the old one, so you'd temporarily end up with three chunks, and at best the two new elements might end up in different "new" chunks.

## Solution overview

Fundamentally, the problem is the combination of two things:

- `std::deque<Node>::emplace_back()` is being called *by* `Node::Node(...)`
- `std::deque<Node>::emplace_back()` is making a call *to* `Node::Node(...)`

Combining these two problems, `std::deque::emplace_back()` ends up calling itself. The solution is therefore to fix one of these two things.

## Specific solutions

1. Use a wrapper function, which I call `make()`. `make()` calls itself, and calls `emplace_back()` (which calls `Node::Node(...)`), but `Node::Node(...)` never calls `emplace_back()`.
2. This is a variation on the idea of (1). It also uses a wrapper function, but it uses reference members (like the original question) so it has to construct the child nodes first.
3. This fixes the other problem: `Node::Node(...)` is allowed to `emplace_back()`, but this time `emplace_back()` is not allowed to construct `Node` objects. The way I do this is that I use a deque of *pointers* to `Node` objects. However, as written this solution is not exception safe, and I consider it much uglier than the other solutions.
4. This is essentially @AMA's ingenious idea: I again use a wrapper function, but this time the wrapper function is called `Node::Node(int, Pool&)`! The point is, this calls itself and `emplace_back()`. But `emplace_back()` calls a *different* constructor, namely the copy constructor, which I write manually to avoid it copying references to temporaries, and which never calls back to `emplace_back()`.
5. Bonus solution! Part of the complexity here is due to using `*this` as a sentinel value. Using pointers with `nullptr` is more conventional. This solution does this (so uses pointer members like solution 1), and creates the child nodes first (like solution 2), and as a bonus the creation is totally non-invasive.

### Solution 1: Wrapper function and pointers

```
#include <deque>

struct Node;
using Pool = std::deque<Node>;

struct Node
{
    Node(int d)
        : level{d}, l{this}, r{this}
    {
    }
    static Node& make(int d, Pool& pool)
    {
        pool.emplace_back(d);
        Node& result = pool.back();
        if (d > 0) {
            result.l = &make(d - 1, pool);
            result.r = &make(d - 1, pool);
        }
        return result;
    }

    int level;
    const Node* l;
    const Node* r;

    int check() const
    {
        if(l != this)
            return l->check() + 1 + r->check();
        else
            return 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int depth{2};
    Pool pool;
    Node& c = Node::make(depth, pool);
    return c.check()==7 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

### Solution 2: Wrapper function with reference members

Note: this changes the order of elements in the `deque`: child elements are inserted first, so they are now earlier than their parents.

```
#include <deque>

struct Node;
using Pool = std::deque<Node>;

struct Node
{
    static Node& make(int d, Pool& pool)
    {
        Node* l = nullptr;
        Node* r = nullptr;
        if (d > 0) {
            l = &make(d - 1, pool);
            r = &make(d - 1, pool);
        }
        pool.emplace_back(d, l, r);
        return pool.back();
    }

    Node(int d, Node* l_ptr, Node* r_ptr)
        : level{d}
        , l{l_ptr ? *l_ptr : *this}
        , r{r_ptr ? *r_ptr : *this}
    {
    }

    int level;
    const Node& l;
    const Node& r;

    int check() const
    {
        if(!(&l == this))
            return l.check() + 1 + r.check();
        else
            return 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int depth{2};
    Pool pool;
    Node& c = Node::make(depth, pool);
    return c.check()==7 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

### Solution 3: pointers in the container

This uses references, and avoids an auxiliary function, and stores elements in the pool in the correct order. In its current form it is *NOT EXCEPTION SAFE* e.g. if the call to `new` for `r` throws an exception (e.g. `std::bad_alloc`) then `l` will not be freed. This would be tricky to sort out, and ultimately I think the other solutions would be neater.

```
#include <deque>
#include <memory>

struct Node;
using Pool = std::deque<std::unique_ptr<const Node>>;

struct Node
{
    Node(int d, Pool& pool)
        : level{d}
        , l{d > 0 ? *new Node(d - 1, pool) : *this}
        , r{d > 0 ? *new Node(d - 1, pool) : *this}
    {
        if (&l != this) {
            pool.emplace_back(&l);
        }
        if (&r != this) {
            pool.emplace_back(&r);
        }
    }

    int level;
    const Node& l;
    const Node& r;

    int check() const
    {
        if(!(&l == this))
            return l.check() + 1 + r.check();
        else
            return 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int depth{2};
    Pool pool;
    Node c(depth, pool);
    return c.check()==7 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

### Solution 4: Two constructors

This is arguably the simplest solution, but I would argue that it's not completely obvious that it doesn't keep any dangling references to temporary objects, unlike solution 1 and solution 2.

```
#include <deque>

struct Node;
using Pool = std::deque<Node>;

struct Node
{
    Node(int d, Pool& pool)
        : level{d}
        , l{d > 0 ? pool.emplace_back(Node(d - 1, pool)) : *this}
        , r{d > 0 ? pool.emplace_back(Node(d - 1, pool)) : *this}
    {
    }

    Node(const Node& other)
        : level{other.level}
        , l{&other.l == &other ? *this : other.l}
        , r{&other.r == &other ? *this : other.r}
    {
    }

    int level;
    const Node& l;
    const Node& r;

    int check() const
    {
        if(!(&l == this))
            return l.check() + 1 + r.check();
        else
            return 1;
    }
};
```

### Bonus solution: Pointers, wrapper function and nullptr

The simplest solution is if you're prepared to use pointers, construct child nodes first, and use `nullptr` instead of `this` as a sentinel value. Note that `Node` is now cleanly separated from `Pool` and `make()`.

```
#include <deque>

struct Node {
    int level;
    const Node* const l;
    const Node* const r;

    Node(int level, const Node* l, const Node* r):
        level(level), l(l), r(r)
    {
    }

    int check() const
    {
        if(l)
            return l->check() + 1 + r->check();
        else
            return 1;
    }
};

using Pool = std::deque<Node>;

Node* make(int d, Pool& pool)
{
    Node* l = d > 0 ? make(d - 1, pool) : nullptr;
    Node* r = d > 0 ? make(d - 1, pool) : nullptr;
    return &pool.emplace_back(d, l, r);
}
```

## Diagram of solutions

[image: Diagram showing calling patterns in solutions]

Comment: I suppose you're right but... can you imagine a solution ("How can the references be correctly initialized?")?

Comment: Standard quote would be a nice addition

Comment: well... if I understand correctly, the point of your solution is transform `l` and `r` in pointer instead of references; I suspect that can be the only reasonable way but (IMHO) would be intriguing a solution that maintain `l` and `r` as references (but no idea how to do it)

Comment: @max66 I added two more solutions, which use reference members instead of pointers. The first allocates `l` and `r` before the parent's constructor is called. The final one doesn't use `std::deque` to actually call the `Node` constructor (so I think that solution is not so nice).

Comment: @ArthurTacca - yes: I was also thinking to something similar to your solution unique-pointer based bat seem to me that your solution is better (sorry but I can't give you more than a +1 :) ); just a little suggestion: in constructors avoid to call input parameters exactly as the member of the class; works but is confusion prone; I suggest you something like `Node(int d, Node* l0, Node* r0) : level{d}, l{l0 ? *l0 : *this}, r{r0 ? *r0 : *this}`

Comment: @max66 Good idea! I actually don't mind constructor arguments with exactly the same name as members if they are copied or moved exactly, but that isn't the case here.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks! I have added it.

Comment: Solution 4 works because the `Node(int, Pool&)` constructor calls itself and `emplace_back()`, but `emplace_back()` only calls the copy constructor `Node(const Node&)`. Then, the important bit is that the copy constructor does *not* call `emplace_back()`. At the end, all references are to `*this` or the return value of `emplace_back()`, so none are to temporaries. Considering that references are syntactic sugar for pointers, it does essentially the same thing as solution 1, in a way that is cleverer but (in my opinion) less clear.

Comment: This is going to take me some time to digest, but I think there is more to solution 4 and I can't shake the feeling that there is still some implementation defined behavior that is being relied upon. Specifically it seems to me as though the constructor is still reentering the deque, but that the copy constructor is saving the day by resetting the l and r references to the `this` of the copied instance.

Comment: @rex I added a diagram showing what calls what in each of the solutions, in case that helps a bit.

Comment: @rex BTW The `*this` stuff is separate from the two-constructor trick really. It's just a symptom of the fact that sometimes there is no suitable value, and you can't have a null reference, so you're using `*this` as a dummy reference. I've made an example using a reference to an actual dummy object, and another using pointers/`nullptr`, but otherwise the same as solution 4. I put them in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/arthur-tacca/9c53fa4725b69453062aa226641d04a8) because the answer's getting a bit long. (Warning: I didn't test that code.)

Comment: I'll take a look. Thanks for a great answer.

Comment: Wow, this isn't an answer, it's an almanach… one remark: In solution 2, you mention that the order of elements is reversed. If this is even considered a problem, it could be solved by swapping the recursive ``make`` calls, and using ``emplace_front`` and ``front``.

Comment: @ArneVogel Good idea, although that would still have different behaviour if you built two unrelated trees using the same pool.

Comment: @ArthurTacca - greath answer! I've written a little answer with (only) a possible solution that is inspired to your 2 and 4 solutions; if you find it interesting, feel free to absorb my solution in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

A solution inspired from solutions 2 and 4 from Arthur Tacca answer (if you like it, give a +1 to Arthur; if you don't like it: it's my fault).

This solution use a second constructor (as solution 4) but call it directly (as delegating constructor) an a static method (inspired by solution 2) used to create the childs of the new node.

Remain unaltered the main point from Arthur: it's necessary to avoid a `emplace_back()` that call itself and insert the child nodes before the father.

Works also with c++11

```
#include <deque>

struct Node;

using Pool = std::deque<Node>;

struct Node
 {
   Node (int d, Pool & pool, Node const * pl, Node const * pr)
      : level { d }, l { pl ? *pl : *this }, r { pr ? *pr : *this }
    { }

   static Node const * getChild (int d, Pool & pool)
    {
      Node const * ret { nullptr };

      if ( d-- > 0 )
       {
         pool.emplace_back(d, pool, getChild(d, pool), getChild(d, pool));

         ret = & pool.back();
       }

      return ret;
    }

   Node (int d, Pool& pool)
      : Node { d, pool, getChild(d, pool), getChild(d, pool) }
    { }

   int level;

   Node const & l;
   Node const & r;

   int check() const
    { return (!(&l == this)) ? l.check() + 1 + r.check() : 1 ; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   int depth{2};
   Pool pool;
   Node c(depth, pool);

   return c.check()==7 ? 0 : 1;
 }
```